# How do i create test record for Product Media Object?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I've written a function that accepts a product id and returns the product Media record associated with that Id. I need to test that method, but I can't create a Product Media record in the test setup method using apex as it is asking for electronicMediaId which can only be created either through CMS or connectApi. Is there any way to produce product media record without using seeAllData= true?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: if you don't need to do DML on the object, you can use libraries like SObject Fabricator that in turn relies on the JSON serialize/deserialize technique